# Java replacing part of repeating code (with methods?)

Tags: java, methods, repeat

I have code, where part of the code repeats, just some changes in name variables, and it can be used. But I have this problem with variables declaring, so I can see them outside the method, then inside the method and then again outside the method. I'm pretty new to Java, so need help with all the static, void, and pretty everything else. :)
Code self works fine, just think I should start write it as it was intended, not just copy parts of it.

```
public class Some Class{
  public static void someMethod() throws Exception {
    ArrayList<Product> someArraylist= new ArrayList<>();
    int p;

/* from this part, the code repeats many times, just the name of the Arraylist is changing
so if I could make some method, I would just call, and give it the name of the ArrayList
it would run the code, execute the System.out.println() and code continues */
for (p = 0; p < someArraylist.size(); p++) {
    if (someArraylist.get(p).getName().contains("Name of Product")) 
        System.out.println("it works");
}
... some more code, not repeating...
}
/*when I create method here, it doesn't know the variables created before,
 not to mention that it knows the values of them : 
"int p" and "Arraylist someArraylist" */

public static void replaceCode(Arraylist nameOfArraylist) {
for (p = 0; p < nameOfArraylist.size(); p++) {
    if (nameOfArraylist.get(p).getName().contains("Name of Product")) 
        System.out.println("it works");
}
}

}
```

Well, when I see it written, it looks pretty bad with me (I think I'm missing some pretty basics about methods), but when I have it already written, I tried sending it, maybe someone helps me.

Comment: If it looks pretty bad to you, I recommend you fix the indentation. It looks pretty bad to me too.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare `p` so early and reuse it in every loop. You can just use the standard `i` variable for the for-loop in the method.

In fact you would be better off using the for-each loop as in

```
for(Product p : nameOfArraylist)
    if(p.getName().contains("Name of Product"))
        System.out.println("It works.");
```

Comment: It's also not the "name of arraylist", it's a "reference to an arraylist".

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your problem there are two posibilities to handle it.
First is to iterate over each List you want to check. There is no need to instantiate p outside the for-loops:

```
public static void someMethod() throws Exception {
    List<Product> list1 = ...
    for(int i = 0; i < list1.size(), i++){
        if (list1.get(i).getName().contains("Name of Product")){
            System.out.println("it works");
        }
    }
    List<Product> list2 = ...
    for(int i = 0; i < list2.size(), i++){
        if (list2.get(i).getName().contains("Name of Product")){
            System.out.println("it works");
        }
    }
    //...repeat and repeat and repeat
}
```

But, as you already mentioned, it would be better so separate such duplicated code to another method:

```
public static void someMethod() throws Exception {
    List<Product> list1 = ...
    List<Product> list2 = ...
    List<Product> list3 = ...
    List<Product> list4 = ...
    iterate(list1);
    iterate(list2);
    iterate(list3);
    iterate(list4);      
}

public static void iterate(List<Product> list){
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(), i++){
        if (list.get(i).getName().contains("Name of Product")){
            System.out.println("it works");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have a Product.java, you could try this:

```
void checkProductInList(List someArrayList, String productName) {
    // I recommend forEach, it's more user friendly.
    for (Product p : someArraylist) {
        if (p.getName().contains(productName)) { 
            System.out.println("it works");
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can call the method like this where you need:

```
checkProductInList(someArrayList, "Keyboard"); // "keyboard" is just a product i typed. It can be anything, as a String.
```